# How to extract X and Y coordinates from LINESTRING in mysql

Tags: mysql, spatial

I am trying to extract X and Y coordinates for specific point inside linestring, but without success. I want to get same results like when I am running SELECT X(POINT(56.7, 53.34)) query and get 56.7 result, but for linestring. 
Here is the example code:

```
SET @ls = 'LineString(1 1,2 2,3 3)';
SELECT AsText(PointN(GeomFromText(@ls),2));//here is the result POINT(2 2)  
select X(AsText(PointN(GeomFromText(@ls),2))));//here I am expecting result 2, but I get null
```

Could anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can don't need the [AsText](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/gis-format-conversion-functions.html#function_astext) function call. Use simply

```
SET @ls = 'LineString(1 1,2 2,3 3)';
SELECT X(PointN(GeomFromText(@ls),2)); -- returns 2
```

The function [PointN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/gis-linestring-property-functions.html#function_pointn) returns a Point object and you need exactly that, not the text representation of it.

Comment: Thank you so much. I did not try only that combination.